# how to show selected item(s) details into another activity using on button click

Tags: android, android-intent, android-emulator

i am fetching data into listview using json parser, once user will click on any of the listview item row then showing that selected item in a whole page, along with Add to Cart button, here i want whenever user will click on that button show item details(only name and cost) to vieworder form and allow user to select more items like:- Shopping Cart Functionality and finally allow user to view their selected ordered items in ViewCart activity,here i am placing code of SingleItem and FinalOrder CODE:-

```
    public class SingleMenuItem extends Activity{
static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
static final String KEY_COST = "cost";
static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "imageUri";
private EditText edit_qty_code;
private TextView txt_total;
private TextView text_cost_code;
private double itemamount = 0;
private double itemquantity = 0;
ListView list;
LazyAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.single);

    Intent in = getIntent();
    String title = in.getStringExtra(KEY_TITLE);
    String thumb_url = in.getStringExtra(KEY_THUMB_URL);
    String cost = in.getStringExtra(KEY_COST);

    ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader(getApplicationContext());

    ImageView imgv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.single_thumb);
    TextView txttitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.single_title);
    TextView txtcost = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.single_cost);
    TextView txtheader = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.actionbar);

    txttitle.setText(title);
    txtheader.setText(title);
    txtcost.setText(cost);
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(thumb_url, imgv);

    text_cost_code = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.single_cost);
    edit_qty_code = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.single_qty);
    txt_total=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.single_total);

    itemamount=Double.parseDouble(text_cost_code.getText().toString());
    txt_total.setText(Double.toString(itemamount));

    edit_qty_code.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {


    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
    int after) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
         itemquantity=Double.parseDouble(edit_qty_code.getText().toString());
         itemamount=Double.parseDouble(text_cost_code.getText().toString());
         txt_total.setText(Double.toString(itemquantity*itemamount));
    }
    });             

    final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> itemsList = 
    new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);            
    adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, itemsList);        
    list.setAdapter(adapter);



    ImageButton addToCartButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.img_add);
    addToCartButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {    



  int position = 0;
HashMap<String, String> map = itemsList.get(position);

    Intent in = new Intent
         (SingleMenuItem.this, com.erachnida.restaurant.versionoct.FinalOrder.class);
    in.putExtra(KEY_TITLE, map.get(KEY_TITLE));
    in.putExtra(KEY_COST, map.get(KEY_COST));
    startActivity(in);
}


   });  


    // Close the activity
   //  finish();

   }}
```

ViewCart:-

```
public class FinalOrder extends Activity
{
static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
static final String KEY_COST = "cost";
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.view);     


Intent in = getIntent();

String title1 = in.getStringExtra(KEY_TITLE);
String cost1 = in.getStringExtra(KEY_COST);

TextView txttitle1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.item_name);
TextView txtcost1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.item_cost);

txttitle1.setText(title1);
txtcost1.setText(cost1);    

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write below Code to get data from intent, it will solve your problem.

```
Bundle bdl=getIntent().getExtras();
String title1 = bdl.getString(KEY_TITLE);
String cost1 = bdl.getString(KEY_COST);
```

Comment: Dipak thanks, i am getting data but i want to get that for all the selected items into another activity, like in Shopping Cart app,user selects an item, then view more, then select another one and store to vieworder page, i need to make same function in my app to show all the selected item(s) whenever user will click on vieworder button, i hope you will help me, by writing some code how can i do that?

Comment: @Stanley Then first save into an arraylist and then use into in next activity.

Comment: i am using code to fetch details into listview using json in that class i am also using ArrayList, but to this i am not getting what code i need to write for ArrayList, can i show you my one of that activity ArrayList Code or you can write needed ArrayList code for me, as you like i am ok

Comment: Dipak i have posted my new singleActivity code with the use of ArrayList please see that one

Comment: @Stanley First make one constant class and declare 2 static arraylist in this class and then use this arraylist in next activity.

Comment: could you please write some code for me, because i have tried my listview click is not working properly and showing unfortunately closed, i know i am doing mistake somewhere

Comment: @Stanley Send me your project on my email id.

Comment: Dipak please write your email address, then i will send you my complete project what i have made yet